# Node.js fs.readdir folder

Tags: node.js, file

I'm getting Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './src/functions/${folder}'

```
for (const folder of functionFolders ){
const functionFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/functions/${folder}').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of functionFiles)
require('./functions/${folder}/${file}')(client);
```

}

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks (`) instead of single quotes (') to use template literals.

```js
const functionFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions/${folder}`).filter(file =>; file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of functionFiles)
require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
```